# Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, token, endpoint, identityserver4

Using IDS4 with debug tracing, the log only gives me a little bit to go on. I'm receiving the above error (Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint) when I post like so:

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/connect/token?grant_type=password&client_id=resClient&client_secret=TopSecret&username=admin&password=admin123
```

On the client side (web browser) I just get

```
{ "error": "invalid_request" }
```

The whole debug log looks like this:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[1]
      Connection id "0HL2NGBR0Q1O4" started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/connect/token?grant_type=password&client_id=resClient&client_secret=TopSecret&username=admin&password=admin123  0
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Mapping found for endpoint: Token, creating handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint[0]
      Processing token request.
warn: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint[0]
      Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint
trce: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.TokenErrorResult
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 348.2168ms 400 application/json
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[9]
      Connection id "0HL2NGBR0Q1O4" completed keep alive response.
```

My code is pretty sparse. Here's the Startup.cs:

```
namespace IDServer4Test
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryClients(Configurations.Clients.GetClients())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configurations.Scopes.GetApiResources());
            services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, Configurations.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, Configurations.ProfileService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace);

            app.UseIdentityServer();
        }
    }
}
```

Clients.cs:

```
public class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "resClient",
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("TopSecret".Sha256()) },

            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
            AllowedScopes = { "myAPI" }
        }
    };
    }
}
```

And Scopes.cs:

```
public class Scopes
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("myAPI", "My API")
        };
    }
}
```

I should be getting back a token response from IdentityServer but just keeps coming back with this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an invalid HTTP request for the token endpoint ;)

Have you checked the spec?
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2

Parameters are passed in the POST body.

The easiest way to request tokens in C# is using the IdentityModel client lib
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2

Comment: According to the RFC all I need is grant_type, username and password. Scope is optional. In any case, adjusting the request with those parameters still doesn't fix the problem. I'm thinking I'm missing some code. Perhaps the IdentityModel library has what I need but I'm kind of new to this technology so I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate it.

Comment: Yes. But as a form post. Not as query string parameters.

Comment: I need to be able to do this query without a web form. Are you saying that I'm using the wrong method to achieve the result I'm after?

Comment: Yes. The spec mandates a form POST with the parameters in the post body.

Comment: Ok, changing the post to use x-www-form-urlencoded allowed it to post successfully. Unfortunately now I've got an "invalid_client". Guess that's probably another problem entirely though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the `scope` you require a token for when making your post. Include `&scope=myAPI` in your request and I think your request will then be valid.